# Is Snape sensationalizing?

Tags: harry-potter

> I can teach you how to bottle fame, brew glory, even stopper death
>    -- Chapter 8, The potion master, Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone

This quote give Snape's almost an almighty aura. Do we know at some moment to what he may refer here?

“Brew glory” might refer to “Felix Felicis” but I am clueless for the other two. It is also possible that at this time, JKR did not thought to much abour the means Snape would use to achieve what he said.

Comment: Well clearly his death stopper isn't that great huehue

Comment: Yeah, since @Voldemort get rid of him without to much a hurdle we might indeed think so ...

Comment: By the way, "stopper death" could also have another meaning. If you put a stopper on a bottle of poison that could cause death, you have now 
"stoppered (a bottle of) death." Personally, I do not think this had been the intended meaning, but just throwing it out there since it would go with the two verbs that had come before it, "bottle" and "brew."